# Firefox freezes when I open facebook.com / mebload trojan

Tags: facebook, firefox, freeze

I don't know what happened to my Firefox (other browsers working fine). I tried every step mentioned on http://support.mozilla.org/en-US/kb/Firefox-hangs, but the problem still remains.

I deleted and completely uninstalled Firefox using Revo Uninstaller, but that did not help. The problem is that while I start typing sites like facebook.com after pressing enter Firefox freezes for a while then the site is opened. This behavior is repeated with every click on the site.

I also noticed that, sometimes, nod32 warns me about MEBLOAD TROJAN in firefox.exe, running in memory. The Firefox version is 11.0 and I also updated my nod32 recently.
I found this link http://forum.malekal.com/trojan-win32-mebload-t36996.html in French, but I don't understand what is described.

Can someone suggest a fix?

Comment: fixed by running combofix.exe

www.combofix.org/download.php

Answer (score 0, accepted):

fixed by running combofix.exe www.combofix.org/download.php